# Defining the set of all edges between a set of paths in a DAG

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

This is a bit of a spin on traditional set notation. I effectively have a set of paths within a DAG, and I would like to re-express these paths into a single global set of edges that I'll call ($E$). To ensure that I retain the information about the paths, I want to subscript each edge with the path and offset within the path. The paths ($P$) are currently expressed as an ordered sets of vertices in the graph for now. For example:

$$P_{i} = \{ v_{0}, ..., v_{n}\} \text{ should allow me to derive edges } \{\tau_{(i,0)}, ... , \tau_{(i,n-1)}\} $$

I've tried to define my set of total set edges across all paths as the following:

$$E = \{ \tau_{(k,i)} \mid P_{k} \in P \land \lvert P_{k} \rvert > 1 \land (\exists v_{i}, v_{j}\in P_{k} \land j=i+1) \}$$

($\tau_{(k,i)}$ *is the set of all edges from all paths k, where the path length is larger than one, and the there are two vertices in the path such that they are consecutive*)

However, I'm not very comfortable with my use of the existential quantifier. I feel like I should be using the universal quantifier somehow, but it doesn't seem to work well in place of the existential one. Is there a better way to express this set of edges?

---

Edit: I think I've got a better definition, after thinking about it for a bit. What do you think?

$$E = \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{N} \{ \tau_{(k,i)} \mid v_{i}, v_{j} \in P_{k} \land j=i+1\}$$